# How to get the feature maps from each layers of a trained model during inference time?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

I have implemented and trained the model from the [following website](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/inferring-a-super-resolution-neural-network-on-raspberry-pi-gpu-89b5456d21ef), and using the author's [source code](https://gist.github.com/lnstadrum/0e2fec1e96bc6791f0ee3487969632ee):

I am now running an image through the trained network and **want to get the network output (feature maps etc.) at every stage**.

#### My Approach

To that end, I have tried making sub-models from groups of layers from the full model (called `sizedModel` in my code) and checking their output.

[image: Diagram of L1 and L2]

I have done that for the first `L1(Conv2D)`

```
L1_inp = sizedModel.layers[1].input
L1_out = sizedModel.layers[1].output
Layer1 = Model(L1_inp,L1_out)
L1_result = Layer1.predict(
    tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(lrImage, axis=0), axis=3)
)

# Save feature maps to greyscale images
Xresult = tf.squeeze(L1_result)
for i in range(Xresult.shape[2]):
    data = (Xresult[:,:,i].numpy() * 255).astype(np.uint8)
    filename = 'tmp_test/result'+str(i).zfill(2)+'.png'
    Image.fromarray(data).save(filename)`
```

the result of `.predict()` on that model is tensor shaped `(1,360,640,12)` which is as expected and the images look fine.

I am now trying to feed that tensor into the layers marked as L2 in the diagram (sizedModel.layers[2-8]).
[image]
The only way I know how to do it is isolated in a new model. To that end I am doing:
# Pick up input shape from output of L1 (1,360,640,12)
_input = tf.keras.Input(shape=L1_result.shape, name="input_layer")

```
# First "tf_op_layer_strided_slice" from large model
_split = largeModel.layers[2](_input)

# First "L2-0 (Conv 3x3)" from large model
_conv = largeModel.layers[5](_split)
```

This results in
# ValueError: Input 0 of layer L2-0 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape
# to have value 4 but received input with shape [None, 1, 360, 4, 12]

```
# Build sub-model from these two layers of the large model
Layer2 = Model(_input,_conv)

# Pass first sub-model (L1) output to this model
Result_L2 = Layer2.predict(L1_result)
```

Why is the `Input 0` of Layer `L2-0` incompatible?
Is there an easier way to debug the output of each layer individually?

Comment: I think it's not quite clear what are you trying to do here but is it something that you want to get the output feature maps of each layer from a model?

Comment: @M.Innat correct. I am trying to get the output feature maps for a single forward pass in the trained model so that I can debug against another implementation.

Comment: That's achievable but can you please add more details to your question? It still not clear what are you really want. Normally we can modify the model to give output feature maps of each layer instead of the last layer only but that really depends on the cases. Also taking some output feature maps from one model and add it to another model is mutual cases. However, if you can add some plug-n-play code, that would be easy to look into that.

Comment: @M.Innat thank you very much for taking the time to help me out. I really appreciate it. I have updated the question. Hope this makes things more clear. Is there an easier way to debug each layer's output tensor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, you want to get **output feature maps of each layer** of a model. Normally, as we mentioned in the comment box, a model with **one (or multiple) inputs** and **one (or multiple) outputs**. But in order to **inspect the activation feature maps** of inside layers, we can adopt some strategies. Some possible scenarios: **(1)**. Want to get output feature maps of each layer in run-time or training time. **(2)**. Want to get output feature maps of each layer in the inference time or after training. And as you quoted:

> I am now running an image through the trained network and want to get
> the network output (feature maps etc.) at every stage.

That goes to number **2**, get the feature maps in inference time. Below is a simple possible workaround to do this. First, we build a model, and then after training, we will modify the trained model to get feature maps of each layer within it (technically creating the same model with some modification).

```
# The model we trained 

input
|
conv1
|
conv2
|
conv3
|
output
|


# The modified model we use for inference 

input
|
conv1 --> outputA [Get Feature Mpas]
|
conv2 --> outputB [G. F. M.]
|
conv3 --> outputC [G. F. M.]
|
output
|
```

---

I'm using the model definition from [here](https://gist.github.com/lnstadrum/0e2fec1e96bc6791f0ee3487969632ee) that you reference in your post.

```
def buildModel(inputSize=(9,9), networkWidth=[48, 24], parBlockSize=12): 
    ....
    ....
    return tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
```

[image]

Now, we iterate over the layers and get each layer output and build a new model.

```
model = buildModel(...)
features_list = [layer.output for layer in model.layers]
activations_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=features_list)
```

Now, if we pass some input to `activations_model`, we will get more than one output, unlike with `model` where we get only the last layer output.

```
img = np.random.random((1, 128, 128, 1)).astype("float32")
activations = activations_model.predict(img)

for i, _ in enumerate(activations):
    print(activations[i].shape)

(1, 128, 128, 1)
(1, 124, 124, 48)
(1, 124, 124, 12)
(1, 124, 124, 12)
(1, 124, 124, 12)
(1, 124, 124, 12)
(1, 122, 122, 8)
(1, 122, 122, 8)
(1, 122, 122, 8)
(1, 122, 122, 8)
(1, 122, 122, 32)
(1, 122, 122, 24)
(1, 122, 122, 12)
(1, 122, 122, 12)
(1, 120, 120, 8)
(1, 120, 120, 8)
(1, 120, 120, 16)
(1, 120, 120, 4)
(1, 240, 240, 1)
```

So, we have total `1 + 48 + 12*6 + 8*6 + 32 + 24 + 16 + 4 + 1 = 246` feature maps from a single instance. Now, we can save these feature maps as we wanted.

```
layer_names = []

for layer in model.layers:
    layer_names.append(layer)

for i, (layer_name, layer_activation) in enumerate(zip(layer_names, activations)):
    n_features = layer_activation.shape[-1]
    feat_maps = tf.squeeze(layer_activation)
    print(feat_maps.shape)

    if n_features == 1:
        tf.keras.preprocessing.image.save_img(
            f'tmp/{layer_name.name}_{n_features}.png',
            tf.expand_dims(feat_maps, axis=-1))
    else:
        for n_feature in range(n_features):
            feat_map = feat_maps[:, :, n_feature]
            tf.keras.preprocessing.image.save_img(
                f'tmp/{layer_name.name}_{n_feature}.png',
                tf.expand_dims(feat_map, axis=-1))
```

Comment: You mean the saved image file looks different?

Comment: Ok, I see both results. But I'm not sure if the difference comes from the methodologies that we are proposing here. I tested the proposed way one diabetic retinopathy data set using efficientnet-b5, and here are some activated results [one](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/17668390/116860347-410aed00-ac23-11eb-9359-1005dac46e98.png) - [two](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/17668390/116860368-46683780-ac23-11eb-90dc-64f6dafd291a.png) , [three](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/17668390/116860381-4bc58200-ac23-11eb-9c8d-4dad79afc916.png)

Comment: I found the problem. When I run the image through the network , I need to pass it with expand_dims as such:
(tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(lrImage, axis=0), axis=3))
I wasn't doing that for your version of the code and therefore the feature maps were not correct!

Comment: I see. Please notify me if there's something you want me to know. And, lastly, here something to consider: ensure that in the way you're saying feature maps, they're the activated output (not just linear transform), and secondly, the saving process, sometimes makes a lot of change. Or, you can gradually check intermediate layer output and inspect likewise: e.g. `tf.keras.Model(old_model.input, old_model.__some_specific_layer_output`)

Comment: Actually, in my above example code, I didn't have to do that but probably you need it. If you notice, I already passed  `np. random.random((1, 128, 128, 1))` shaped samples, so I didn't need to expend any dimension for the model's input.